# uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier") is always null

Tags: java, android, oauth, signpost

I am new to OAuth and I'm developing an Android app that requires it and I'm using the signpost library.

I believe I have it all working up to the point where I can get the token using

```
String token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
```

Which returns correctly however the very next line

```
String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
```

returns null. I have debugged and inspected uri which is initialized as

```
 Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
```

And it does not appear to have a key "oauth_verifier"

The verifier being null causes an OAuthExpectationFailedException when I try the ofllowing line

```
provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifier);
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the verifier is null I am using a callback not OOB.

I have seen in other questions and guides the likes of this in the response:

```
dat=myapp://twitter?oauth_token=tJpJHOOwoTGMwdvHyYbfX2tyHKOp0Y2kdRRZf3sM&
oauth_verifier=xc49oM8eVVmK46ZSLz2RMT2uqXn3SxrMxf5ZAMXaD2Y
```

Mine is similar but without the ouath_verifier key.

Here is where I send the initial intent which works and I get a return

```
        String clientKey = "xxxxxxx";
        String clientSecret = "yyyyyyyyy";

        CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer  consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(clientKey,clientSecret);


        provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(URL_Request_Token,
                URL_Access_Token, 
                URL_Authorize";
        provider.setOAuth10a(true);


        try {
            String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,CALLBACK_URI.toString());

            String token = consumer.getToken(); 
            String secret = consumer.getTokenSecret();

            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
         }
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A problem I had while developing a twitter interaction sample is that I forgot to set a callback url from the twitter app console.

[image]

If you don't do that, your application won't be redirected and so it won't be able to grap the verifier token.

PROMO MODE ON

However, if you feel particularly brave, I've been working on this library [PostManLib](https://github.com/fedepaol/PostmanLib--Rings-Twice--Android) lately and I am looking for beta testers. It should handle all the async oauth interaction using the well know scribe library under the hood.

PROMO MODE OFF

Comment: Thanks for the help but I seem to be ok on the callback in that I am getting back something like this: dat=myapp://twitter?oauth_token=tJpJHOOwoTGMwdvHyYbfX2tyHKOp0Y2kdRRZf3sM so it seems I'm just not getting the verifier.

Comment: Hi fedepaol!!I have set up the callback url in my twitter console and it is redirecting to that webpage but I didn't get verifier???